# Excel cell set in UK date format, looks like UK format but calcuates as if it is in US format

Tags: formatting

I am developing a excel sheet where I have two date cells.  In both cell set up I have set it as English UK i.e. dd/mm/yy.  In both cells after doing this they appear in English UK format.

However because I use these dates to calculate the difference between I have found the calculations were miles out.  I have now tried in the cell itself to type the date in English US format i.e. mm/dd/yy even though it is still set up as UK format and it starting calculating the difference in dates correctly.  Again type in US format, in the cell itself it appears as UK format and they calcuate correctly.

Put simply the 1st January 2018 looks in the cell as 10/01/18.  If the other date I am calculating is the 12/01/18 I should get an answer of 2.  However although the cells still look like that the calculation is doing it as US format and calculating between 1st October and the 1st December.

Why, Are you confused.  Me too.

Comment: Confused? Will excel and dates? No, dates going wrong is the expected behaviour in excel. (not trying to make fun here, it really is what I expect in excel).  What sometimes helped my is starting a new excel sheet, setting up the date format (first!), then entering information. Doing it the other way around sometimes does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is odd with dates.  It really doesn't do math on the actual date in the format we read it.  It converts to an integer in background in a universal format.  That said, you should be able to do what you are trying to do.

Also consider that there are a lot of date math formulas in Excel, see the links at the bottom.

[Screen Shot of what I think you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xELWM.png)

[Screen shot of cell formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHaOf.png)

[Screen shot of cell formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrEiM.png)

[Screen shot of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta7i2.png)

Also you can take a look at these: 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1143-excel-convert-number-to-date.html

https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/excel-date-and-time-formulas--cms-28023

Best of luck,
G^2